# java.lang.String com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.getString(java.lang.String) on a null object reference

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I use firestore.DocumentSnapshot.getString to fetch user data and its actually worked and I got user data on interface , the problem is whenever I tried to signOut an crash occurs says **" involve virtual method on null object reference "**

can please help guys ...?

```
    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sttings, container, false);
        firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        emailedit = view.findViewById(R.id.emailedit);
        phoneedit = view.findViewById(R.id.phoneedit);
        useredit = view.findViewById(R.id.useredit);
        chngpass = view.findViewById(R.id.chngpass);
        signin = view.findViewById(R.id.signin);
        signin.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        signout = view.findViewById(R.id.signout);
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        fStore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        FirebaseFirestoreSettings settings = new FirebaseFirestoreSettings.Builder()
                .setTimestampsInSnapshotsEnabled(true)
                .build();
        fStore.setFirestoreSettings(settings);


        if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            userId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
            DocumentReference documentReference = fStore.collection("users").document(userId);
            documentReference.addSnapshotListener(getActivity(), new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot,
                                    @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                    phoneedit.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Phone Number"));
                    useredit.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Username"));
                    emailedit.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Email Address"));

                }
            });
        }

        signout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent signoutint = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(signoutint);
                getActivity().finish();
            }
        });


        return view;
    }
}
```

beginning of the Crash :

```
2020-04-15 08:11:47.051 11045-11045/com.example.sendthro E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.sendthro, PID: 11045
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.sendthro.settings$1.onEvent(settings.java:70)
        at com.example.sendthro.settings$1.onEvent(settings.java:65)
```

Comment: post your database too

Answer (score 0):

Having  this constructor was the problem :)!!

```
 public settings(){
        //Required empty Constructor
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this code, it will solve your problem:

```
DocumentReference documentReference = mFireStore.collection("Users").document(userId);
        documentReference.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if(documentSnapshot.exists()) {
                    TextView_fullName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("full name"));
                    TextView_firstName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("first name"));
                    TextView_lastName.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("last name"));
                    TextView_email.setText(documentSnapshot.getString("Email"));
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

            }
        });
```